# Extract port number from netstat command

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I have the following output of the command netstat:

```
netstat -taunp | grep hgd
tcp        0      0 10.1.1.1:601            10.1.1.2:935            ESTABLISHED 842/hgd
tcp        0      0 10.1.1.1:55394          10.1.1.2:3490           ESTABLISHED 842/hgd
```

I want to extract from this output the port number **601**.
please note that this port is random and port 935 is hard coded and exists in many netstat lines

any suggestion?

Comment: Have you try using awk to separate columns ? Then a second one for the port.

Comment: `netstat -taunp | awk -F'[:[:space:]]+' '/hgd/ && $7 == "935" { print $5 }'`

Comment: Many thanks to  @WiktorStribiżew , your proposal works fine

Comment: I think the question (and my answer) is downvoted because of seemingly no effort. Note that `-taunp` and `grep hgd` are already a sufficient proof of efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
netstat -taunp | awk -F'[:[:space:]]+' '/hgd/ && $7 == "935" { print $5 }'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/CwrxSu)

**Details**

- `-F'[:[:space:]]+'` - sets the field separator to one or more occurrences of `:` and/or whitespace
- `'/hgd/ && $7 == "935"` - if the line contains `hgd` and Field 7 is equal to `935` then
- `{ print $5 }'` - print Field 5.

Answer (score 1):

Awk is the tool for what you want :

```
netstat -taunp | grep <your_grep> | awk '{print $4}' | awk -F ':' '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I like to do it:

```
netstat -taunp | awk '/hgd/ && $5~/:935$/ {split($4,a,":");print a[2]}'
```

grep is not needed, since `awk` can find `hgd` by it self:

- `/hgd/ && $5~/:935$/` find line with `hgd` and fifth field ends with `:935`then do:
- `split($4,a,":")` split 4 filed inn to array `a` using `:` as separator
- `print a[2]` print second part of array `a` where the ports are.